# Migrating my GViz to Fusion Tables Api v1 w/o 500 row limit

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-fusion-tables

I have searched for a way to get around the 500 row limit on my query and have found a acouple of examples that *almost* help me. [Here](http://northdakotarigsmap.com/500limit.html) is a working example.
My code here queries a list of "operators" and based on that selection dynamically returns the "wells" that they operate. It works but is limited by the GViz to 500 rows, so what I read is that I need to use the new Fusion Tables Api which passes JSON so I won't have to use GViz and I can get all of my rows. I wish I knew how to do that.
Can someone please help me migrate this or make it so I can return all of my rows instead just the 500? Thank you so much!

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>

    <!--
      copyright (c) 2011 Google inc.

      You are free to copy and use this sample.
      License can be found here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/faq/#license
    -->

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <title>northdakotarigsmap.com - Wells Map</title>

    <style>
      body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
      #map_canvas { height: 650px; width:900px; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {});

    var myLatLng = null;
    var markloc = null;
    var cachedFirstOption = ""; // Save the selected option
    var tableid = '1X1BA0s3R8fBfPuiuuYUYsWhV_u_6RWVMVoDqsAY'; // table id
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer();

    // Initialize the map and set the layer
    function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.724544549099676, -100.43701171875), //the center lat and long
        scaleControl: true,
        zoom: 7, //zoom
        zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //the map style
      });

      layer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: 'geometry',
          from: tableid
        }

      });
      layer.setMap(map);
    }

    // The following function, changeData, runs when the user selects an option from the first
    // select menu. This function removes any options from the second menu. If the option
    // is All, it resets the query to show all results on the map. Otherwise, it updates 
    // the data on the map to match the selected option, then sends a gviz query to update the
    // second select menu.
    function changeData(firstOption) {

        // Remove any options from second menu
        secondSelect = document.getElementById("wnames");
        numChildren = secondSelect.childNodes.length;
        for(i = 1; i < numChildren; i++) {
            secondSelect.removeChild(secondSelect.childNodes[1]);
        }

        if(firstOption == "%") {
            layer.setOptions({
              query: {
                select: 'geometry',
                from: tableid
              }
            });

        } else {
          // Save the option and update the map
          cachedFirstOption = firstOption;
          updateMap(firstOption, "%");


            var queryText = encodeURIComponent("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT 'Well Name', COUNT() FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Operator' LIKE '" + firstOption + "' GROUP BY 'Well Name'&key=AIzaSyAkmt7K8ArFRtBpiI6om-d2uSuI9qbiiAY");

            // Set the callback function which will update the second menu
            query.send(getData);
        }
    }
    //
            //
    //I can't get the following code to work
    //
            //
    // This function, getData, is called when query results are returned. It adds options
    // to the second select menu based on the results of the query.
    function getData(response) {

      // Get the number of rows
      numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();

      // Add options to the select menu based on the results
      secondSelect = document.getElementById("wnames");  
      for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        newoption = document.createElement('option');
        newoption.setAttribute('value', response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0));
        newoption.innerHTML = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
        secondSelect.appendChild(newoption);
      }  
    }

    // Update the data displayed on the map
    function updateMap(firstOption, secondOption) {
      secondOption = secondOption.replace("'", "\\'");
        layer.setOptions({
          query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: tableid,
            where: "'Operator' LIKE '" + firstOption + "' AND 'Well Name' LIKE '" + secondOption + "'"
          }
        });
    }

    //


    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize();">



    <div id="map_canvas"></div>

    <div id="select1" style="absolute">
    Operator: <select id="delivery" onchange="changeData(this.value);">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <option value="ABRAXAS PETROLEUM CORP.">ABRAXAS PETROLEUM CORP.</option>
    <option value="AMERICAN EAGLE ENERGY CORPORATION">AMERICAN EAGLE ENERGY CORPORATION</option>
    <option value="BAYTEX ENERGY USA LTD">BAYTEX ENERGY USA LTD</option>
    <option value="BRIGHAM OIL & GAS, L.P.">BRIGHAM OIL & GAS, L.P.</option>
    <option value="BURLINGTON RESOURCES OIL & GAS COMPANY">BURLINGTON RESOURCES OIL & GAS COMPANY</option>
    <option value="CONTINENTAL RESOURCES, INC.">CONTINENTAL RESOURCES, INC.</option>
    <option value="CORINTHIAN EXPLORATION (USA) CORP">CORINTHIAN EXPLORATION (USA) CORP</option>
    <option value="CORNERSTONE NATURAL RESOURCES LLC">CORNERSTONE NATURAL RESOURCES LLC</option>
    <option value="CRESCENT POINT ENERGY U.S. CORP.">CRESCENT POINT ENERGY U.S. CORP.</option>
    <option value="DENBURY ONSHORE, LLC">DENBURY ONSHORE, LLC</option>
    <option value="ENDURO OPERATING, LLC">ENDURO OPERATING, LLC</option>
    <option value="ENERPLUS RESOURCES USA CORPORATION">ENERPLUS RESOURCES USA CORPORATION</option>
    <option value="EOG RESOURCES, INC.">EOG RESOURCES, INC.</option>
    <option value="FIDELITY EXPLORATION & PRODUCTION COMPANY">FIDELITY EXPLORATION & PRODUCTION COMPANY</option>
    <option value="G3 OPERATING, LLC">G3 OPERATING, LLC</option>
    <option value="GMX RESOURCES INC">GMX RESOURCES INC</option>
    <option value="HESS CORPORATION">HESS CORPORATION</option>
    <option value="HUNT OIL COMPANY">HUNT OIL COMPANY</option>
    <option value="KODIAK OIL & GAS (USA) INC.">KODIAK OIL & GAS (USA) INC.</option>
    <option value="LIBERTY RESOURCES LLC">LIBERTY RESOURCES LLC</option>
    <option value="MARATHON OIL COMPANY">MARATHON OIL COMPANY</option>
    <option value="MOUNTAIN VIEW ENERGY INC.">MOUNTAIN VIEW ENERGY INC.</option>
    <option value="MUREX PETROLEUM CORPORATION">MUREX PETROLEUM CORPORATION</option>
    <option value="NEWFIELD PRODUCTION COMPANY">NEWFIELD PRODUCTION COMPANY</option>
    <option value="NORTH PLAINS ENERGY, LLC">NORTH PLAINS ENERGY, LLC</option>
    <option value="OASIS PETROLEUM NORTH AMERICA LLC">OASIS PETROLEUM NORTH AMERICA LLC</option>
    <option value="OXY USA INC.">OXY USA INC.</option>
    <option value="PETRO-HUNT, L.L.C.">PETRO-HUNT, L.L.C.</option>
    <option value="QEP ENERGY COMPANY">QEP ENERGY COMPANY</option>
    <option value="SAMSON RESOURCES COMPANY">SAMSON RESOURCES COMPANY</option>
    <option value="SEQUEL ENERGY, LLC">SEQUEL ENERGY, LLC</option>
    <option value="SINCLAIR OIL AND GAS COMPANY">SINCLAIR OIL AND GAS COMPANY</option>
    <option value="SLAWSON EXPLORATION COMPANY, INC.">SLAWSON EXPLORATION COMPANY, INC.</option>
    <option value="SM ENERGY COMPANY">SM ENERGY COMPANY</option>
    <option value="TRIANGLE USA PETROLEUM CORPORATION">TRIANGLE USA PETROLEUM CORPORATION</option>
    <option value="TRUE OIL LLC">TRUE OIL LLC</option>
    <option value="WATERWORKS EAST FORK, LLC">WATERWORKS EAST FORK, LLC</option>
    <option value="WHITING OIL AND GAS CORPORATION">WHITING OIL AND GAS CORPORATION</option>
    <option value="WPX ENERGY WILLISTON, LLC">WPX ENERGY WILLISTON, LLC</option>
    <option value="XTO ENERGY INC.">XTO ENERGY INC.</option>
    <option value="ZAVANNA, LLC">ZAVANNA, LLC</option>
    <option value="ZENERGY, INC">ZENERGY, INC</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <!-- Important: keep the option on the same line as the select tag here because any newlines
         will be considered child elements of the select node -->
    Well Names: <select id="wnames" onchange="updateMap(cachedFirstOption, this.value)"><option id="secondOption" value="%">--Make selection--</option></select>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking, for but may help: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide

Comment: It is a valuable resource, but it doesn't quite help me. I have used the GViz examples on your page before and they are awesome. Now I've discovered that my dropdown queries return more than 500 rows and the new API returns JSON without having to implement GViz. I just don't know how to do that. I have updated my question above with a link to a working example. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than asking someone to port your code for you, perhaps you could post your code that you attempted to modify and ask questions about where you run into trouble. [Here is an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=14.620282&lng=-90.504716&zoom=12&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20%20geometry,%20name,%20description%20FROM&tableid=1npi-QWwoZ6LP_9wwHiwiG2omzMm6R9Qoj5aMjkM) that uses the Fusion Tables API v1 to display markers.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have changed the query to reflect V1. The first drop down select works but the second one is dynamic and queries the table based on the first one. This is what I can't figure out now. Also, how hard would it be to leave the map hidden until the final selection, and then appear?